# Populate all the nodes of an object in JavaScript based on a given path

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have an object like so:

```
{
  id: 1,
  name: 'E1',
  children: [
    {
      id: 2,
      name: 'E2',
      children: [
        {
          id: 3,
          name: 'E3',
        },
        {
          id: 7,
          name: 'E7',
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      name: 'E4',
      children: [
        {
          id: 5,
          name: 'E5',
          children: [
            {
              id: 6,
              name: 'E6',
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
};
```

And I would like to get the tree with the object data filled in as well for a given path, for example `children.0.children.0` should return

```
{
  id: 1,
  name: 'E1',
  children: [
    {
      id: 2,
      name: 'E2',
      children: [
        {
          id: 3,
          name: 'E3',
        },
      ],
    }
 ]
```

}

I have something like this, but it doesn't really work:

```
const createPath = (obj, path, value = null) => {
  let current = obj;
  while (path.length > 1) {
    const [head, ...tail] = path;
    path = tail;
    if (current[head] === undefined) {
      current[head] = {};
    }
    current = current[head];
  }
  current[path[0]] = value;
  return obj;
};
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be a solution but it doesn't cover all the scenarios, just the happy path. I don't know which are the expected scenarios.

```
function createPath(obj, path) {
  var newObject = Object.assign({}, obj);
  var aux;
  var keys = path.split('.');
  var i = 0;
  while(i < keys.length) {
    if (aux) {
      aux[keys[i]] = [aux[keys[i]][keys[i+1]]];
      aux = aux[keys[i]][keys[i+1]];
    } else {
      aux = obj[keys[i]][keys[i+1]];
      newObject[keys[i]] = [aux];
    }
    i = i + 2;
  }
  
  return newObject;
}
```